# Win 7 Remote Desktop and Remote Printing Not Working

Tags: remote-desktop, printer, windows-server-2008-r2

We have 2 offices located in Sydney and Melbourne, and the colleagues use Remote Desktop from Melbourne office to a Windows Server 2008 R2 box in Sydney, and want to print out something to the printer in Melbourne.

I've checked 'printer' in local devices tab in 'Remote Desktop', but in the RDP session, I still could not find the printer.

What should I do to make it work?

Comment: I checked 'Disable' in 'Do not allow client printer redirection' in `Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Remote Desktop Services > Remote Desktop Session Host > Printer Redirection > Do not allow client printer redirection`, but when I launched 'RSOP.msc', the redirection of windows printer is still checked and greyed out.

Answer (score 1):

Well, by default redirected printer will use Microsoft Easy Printer driver, but this driver doesn't work for all the printers from all OEMs. So in some situation, we need to install the OEM driver on the remote server to help to printer redirection process.
You can verify if any event ID 1111 has been created on the server during the logon, for information about 1111: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc775141(v=ws.10).aspx

After installing the OEM driver on the server, you can consider to disable "Use Terminal Services Easy Print printer driver first" GPO to avoid using easy printer driver. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff519193(v=ws.10).aspx